# How to record log information from a specific class into a specific file?

Tags: java, log4j

currently, I wish to save all the log from a specify class in specific file.
In my class, I've already instantiated my logger, and in my `log4j.properties` I do not know what information to write, in order to log all informations of this specific class in a specific file.

If someone has a example, I take it :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic example of a log4j.properties file that can get you started:

```
log4j.logger.com.yourpackage.yourclass=INFO, YourLoggerName

log4j.appender.YourLoggerName=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.YourLoggerName.File=/path/to/logfile/forthisappender
log4j.appender.YourLoggerName.MaxFileSize=5M
log4j.appender.YourLoggerName.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.YourLoggerName.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayou
log4j.appender.YourLoggerName.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

There's more complete info [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/)

Answer (score 1):

*Hi, you can do by one of this way,*

**Method-1 :**

First of all prepared `2-separate log4j` configuration file let's say for example,

```
 1. log4JMy.properties ( for whole application , we can called it default)
 2. log4jMy2.properties ( for specific class here in your case )
```

into your specific class you can `re-configure log4j` properties likewise,

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4jMy2.properties");*
```

which will modify existence `log4j` configuration and you can `override` it by your `log4jMy2.properties` file.

so for that class works perfectly, however again you need to `re-set to default` so that again get back to `log4j` works normally/default manner.

---

**Method-2 :**

into your log4j.properties file,

assign different LEVEL, with suitable configuration changes, 
for-example,

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,FILE,ERROR_FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.file=${catalina.base}/logs/myApplicationLogs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.file=${catalina.base}/logs/error_myApplicationLogs.log
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

As per above configuration , while from application ,

```
LOG.debug("some text"); // it will print into myApplicationLogs.log file
```

wherever,
if you are write,

```
LOG.error("some erroneous text "); // it will print into error_myApplicationLogs.log file.
```

---

> it will print logs as per log4j configuration file-wise into your corresponds logging file, best of luck...!